# React - second layer of object in list is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new in React and I decided to do semi-solo projects (meaning that I take some projects from tutorial and give myself little tasks to simulate tasks on job).
I ran on multiple errors in my code and I am unsure how to solve them (also any tip's on how to google correctly issues I faced would be much appreciated)

Issues I am currently facings are:

1. In App.js line 76,77 it says that object from response is undefined, but when I was reaching 1 country I fetched it that way.

```
const constantWeatherList = weatherConst.map(el => {
    return <ConstantWeather 
              cityId={el.id} 
              cityName={el.name} 
              country={el.sys.country}  <-- not working
              temperature={el.main.temp} <-- not working
              />
  })
```

2. In components/ConstantWeather -> constant weather css is not working? But everything is imported correctly, do I need to do something with webpack in order to work and will it mess up with other css in code which is in index.css
3. In console I get unique key error even tho I passed to component unique key(cityId) in line 74

```
function constantWeather(props) {
    return (
        <div className={classes.Card} key={props.cityId}> <-- I set it here
            <div>{props.cityName}, {props.country}</div>
            <div>{props.temperature}</div>
            <img />
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
  return <ConstantWeather 
              cityId={el.id} <-- it is here
              cityName={el.name} 
              country={el.sys.country} 
              temperature={el.main.temp} 
              />
  })
```

Maybe this is not the way to post questions, if I am breaking any rules please let me know.

Comment: As much as is needed needs to be in your question see [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]@matej, if you are looking for updates I hope this will work for you.
https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-shockley-o1dzo?file=/src/App.js

```
const ConstantWeather = props => {
  return (
    <div className="Card" key={props.cityId}>
      <div>
        {props.cityName}, {props.country}
      </div>
      <div>{props.temperature}</div>
      <img alt="" />
    </div>
  );
};

const ConstantWeatherList = props =>
  (props.weatherConst || [])
    .filter(el => el) // Filter null if you getting from API
    .map(el => {
      return (
        <ConstantWeather
          key={el.id}
          cityId={el.id}
          cityName={el.name}
          country={el.sys.country}
          temperature={el.main.temp}
        />
      );
    });

<ConstantWeatherList weatherConst={data} />

// Styles
.Card {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: @matej - I have create Pull Request to your Git repository https://github.com/matej24/weather-app/pull/1

Comment: Thank you very much! I most certainly look for updates and to see how other devs think! I have new version so I will upload it soon!

Comment: @Matej, just merge Pull Request and see what you want. :) - https://github.com/matej24/weather-app/pull/1/files

Comment: @Matej, That's great!

Comment: @Matej, if you solve your issue then mark the answer which solved your issue. And I am willing to check for your updates if you want.

Comment: Hi @Alona! I marked Aniket's answer as solution only because I used his solution first, I am glad that you answer me with your solution I learned something from you too as well! I did an update on project now and I will not add any extra solution to it anymore, I will do refactor where I will pull chunks from App.js into small components so it will look clean. Im making small projects as portfolio for future employment and you are most welcome to give me insight on my code and what I pushed now!

Comment: @Matej, maybe you chose the correct answer but you don't see what issue you will get with his code. I already commented edge case for that. I wish you good luck with your new employment. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To solve the 1st issue you will need to wait for the api to successfully retrieve data and then only you should map on the data. So what you could do is you set initial state for weatherConst as an empty array like below

```
const [weatherConst, setWeatherConst] = useState([]);
```

And then while mapping on the data you could check the length of the fetched data. While check you should do boolean operation not just `length` check.

```
let constantWeatherList = weatherConst.length > 0 && weatherConst.map(el => {
    return <ConstantWeather 
              key={el.id}
              cityId={el.id} 
              cityName={el.name} 
              country={el.sys.country} 
              temperature={el.main.temp} 
              />
  })
```

Remember, this is just an example and there are multiple ways to do the same thing.

2. For CSS issue you will need to assign a proper class to the div as className="Card"
3. For the 3rd issue you need to assign key to ConstantWeather component as shown in the code above.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! 1st and 3rd issues is resolved with your example :)
For second issues I am not quite sure what you meant

Comment: Sry, you used Material UI?

Comment: @Alona No, I used pure css

Comment: Hm... Regarding second issues, if I use it like that just naming it "Card" then it may interfere with other css? What is the best way to do that?

Comment: This is the code you need
 <div className="Card" key={props.cityId}>
            <div>{props.cityName}, {props.country}</div>
            <div>{props.temperature}</div>
            <img />
        </div>

Comment: @Matej this should apply the css for card class to the div in constantWeather component

Comment: @Matej, @Aniket, `weatherConst.length && weatherConst.map` - this code is totally wrong. you need to update it with `weatherConst.length > 0 && weatherConst.map` or something can be improved. If `weatherConst` has zero length like `[]` then you will get into trouble. Thanks

Comment: @Alona if weatherConst.length returns 0 then the code wont be executed further. This would handle the situation where arrays is []. Thanks

Comment: @AniketRane, maybe you are right. But did you tried at least once? I guess you will find answer yourself if you try with `[]`. If I am wrong the feel free to flag me :)

Comment: @Alona Yes i did run this code and if you see i have set the initial state to an empty array.

Comment: @AniketRane, https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-nightingale-qr084?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Alona, https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-pine-ixhbk?file=/src/App.js, like i said the code is printing the length of the array i.e 0 which is getting printed. But it is not going within the map statement Your's is also right but since yours is a boolean condition nothing is getting printed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220234/discussion-between-aniket-rane-and-alona).

Comment: @Matej please use the updated solution that Alana has suggested where you do the boolean check

Comment: @Alona I changed your answer to solution and change it to ```weatherConst.length > 0``` on git. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You should add a null check in order not to take `undefined` error from API responses for nested objects. You need to check whether `el.sys` is defined or not.
2. Try to use normal classes in CSS. Just import the CSS file and use strings as a classname.
3. You must set the key to the element that comes after from map function. For this case, it should be

`<ConstantWeather key={city.id} />`

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, any tip on where is correct to add that check?

Comment: You can add this control to prop directly. el.sys ? el.sys.country : ' '. It can be something like that